# EF Core 1.1 Migration - The current CSharpHelper cannot scaffold literals of type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This seems to be a really obscure error, and I don't even know where to start with it...

> The current CSharpHelper cannot scaffold literals of type
>   'System.Func`3[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator]'.
>   Configure your services to use one that can.

This is occurring when I run

```
dotnet ef migrations add initial
```

**Update 1 - based on Rob's question**

The architecture of the application uses a rich domain model, so there are a few "workarounds" to get things like encapsulated collections, and Jimmy Bogard's typed enumeration pattern working.

Each domain model object has it's own `EntityTypeBuilder` class in the data access layer, all of which are called from `OnModelCreating` in the `DbContext`. These also output some information to the `Console`, so I can see that the builder isn't causing any errors (none of them are at this point).

The `DbContext` only exposes `DbSet` for aggregate root entities, or to put it another way, only entities that have a corresponding repository class. The rest of the domain model objects are navigation properties, and therefore do not require `DbSet` to be exposed via the `DbContext`.

Platform specifics (as far as I'm aware)

- .NET Core 1.1 (Runtime + SDK)
- EF Core 1.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 1.0.0-preview2-final
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 1.0.0-preview2-final

Comment: What are you models defined as?

Comment: @Rob, I'm not sure I fully understand your question?

Comment: Sorry - I mean, at a *quick* glance, it appears that it's failing to scaffold your models. That is, it'll generate SQL tables based on your in-memory models. You'd be defining them in your context class. Something like: `DBSet<Person> People { get; set; }`. `Person` may be exposing a property type that EF can't translate to a SQL type.

Comment: @Rob I've updated my question to hopefully shed some light on your last question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a .NET Core 1.1 runtime but the old tooling packages (you should be using the latest tooling, as of this date it is **preview4**, which is still in *alpha*, contrary to the runtime - *yeah, not very intuitive at first*)

In summary, this is a [Known Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7174)

- Update your *project.json* to use **preview4** as stated in [Announcing Entity Framework Core 1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/)

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4"
}
```

- You may, or may not need to fix the SDK version by using a *global.json* just above the *src* folder which should contain your code as [explained in Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingASPNETCore11ApplicationsToAzureUsingGitDeploy.aspx)

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Just to give you a more complete answer, this is how my *project.json* and my sample project looks like (all done in VS Code):

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  }
}
```

[image: VS Code Project Layout]