# EF Migrations: The parameter 'frameworkName' cannot be an empty string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget, entity-framework-core

I'm following some tutorials on plural sight on how to setup my first web api using .netcore. I'm having an issue trying to run my first migration:

`PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration
Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The parameter 'frameworkName' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: frameworkName"`

I understand it's saying there is a constructor somewhere with one argument that is empty; however, I have no idea where this "frameworkName" parameter is. I'm assuming it's some internal EF mechanism.

**What class is this error message referencing?**

This is my simple entity setup

```
public class ShackupContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public ShackupContext(DbContextOptions<ShackupContext> options):base(options)
    {

    }
}  


    public class Post
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
I have updated my dbcontext to call the base class constructor as @ViktorsTelle suggested.

My project is setup different than any tutorials I have followed. The main difference is my entities are contained in their own project as opposed to being in the api project itself.
[image]
This led me to believe that running Add-Migration on the Shackup.Data project itself did not require me to register my dbcontext inside of my api project. I did it anyway to see what would happen:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddDbContext<ShackupContext>(o => 
        o.UseNpgsql(Configuration["connectionStrings:postgres"],
        a => a.MigrationsAssembly("Shackup.Data")));
    }
```

Once I did that I managed to get a little further in the migration process. I am now getting
`PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration
The specified deps.json [C:\Users\campo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Shackup\src\Shackup.Api\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Shackup.Api.deps.json] does not exist
Process finished with non-zero exit code`

So I took a look at that directory and indeed it was missing the file; however, the file is being output to a child folder of that directory.

[image]

The deps.json file is located inside the win10-x64 folder. I can simply copy and paste to the required folder but now I am faced with a new question:

**Why is Nuget package manager console looking in the wrong directory?**
Or possibly: How can I change this to look in the correct place?

**Update 2**

I have updated all my project dependencies in both projects. Here are the two files for the data and the api projects below

*API*

```
{
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
"Shackup.Data": "1.0.0-*",
"Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
},

"tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
},

"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.1": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
},

"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
},

"runtimeOptions": {
"configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
}
},
"runtimes": {
"win10-x64": {},
"win81-x64": {}
},

"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "**/*.cshtml",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]
},

"scripts": {
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
}
}
```

*DATA*

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",

"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
},

 "frameworks": {
"netstandard1.6": {
  "imports": "dnxcore50"
}
},
"tools": {
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
}
}
```

Comment: The first thing that I have noticed is the lack of base class call in constructor. Please add : base(options) to constructor.

Comment: Which version of **Visual Studio** and specially **NuGet** are you using? You will need **VS 2015 Update 3** and **NuGet v 3.5** to use .NET Core EF commands

Comment: Hello, I do have v. 3.5 nuget as well as VS2015 Enterprise Update 3: 14.0.25431.01

Comment: @ViktorsTelle I missed that and added it.

Comment: Not sure if it's related but your dependencies seem to be wrong, the "tooling packages" inside "tools" are "preview4", but not your tooling dependencies. Can you modify your `project.json` to [resemble this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176240/ef-core-1-1-migration-the-current-csharphelper-cannot-scaffold-literals-of-typ/41178855#41178855), then do a package restore and re-test?

Comment: To your edits... did you select a *Startup Project* in NuGet before running the command? Or else did you add the `-StartupProjectName` switch to your nuget command?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't even matter what project I target the command at. It's the same result

Comment: To your last edit, don't you need **[Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design/)** ?

Comment: I have compared your project.json settings with my project. The main difference that I noticed is that you have this configuration, but I don't: "runtimes": {
"win10-x64": {},
"win81-x64": {}
},

Comment: @AndrésRobinet good catch! I thought that was supposed to install with the Npgsql.EntityFramewrkCore.PostgreSQL package. I just added it but still the same issue

Comment: @ViktorsTelle yes my project did not have that when I first created it. Then when I tried to build I would get an error stating I had no `runtimes` in my project.json

I can attribute all these issues to mistakes I made while creating this project. They were mistakes like renaming projects, creating .netfull projects by mistake, deleting this, recreating new ones. I know I can restart completely from scratch since I'm not that far into it but I'm trying to stick it through to learn as much from this as possible

Comment: I don't like that runtime option either. It seems to be the cause of the .deps.json file being placed in the wrong location. For reference: here is the error I get when commenting those runtimes out: `Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' FILE: Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets`

Comment: (https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/project.json) runtimes is ok in the web app. The only thing I don't like is that `Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0"`, you should not need that at all, but maybe a `"NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"` dependency instead. Why? Because `netcoreapp1.1` in the `frameworks` section already implies a dependency on the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` platform package

Comment: And... change the `imports` section to depend on `dnxcore50` instead of `dotnet5.6`

Comment: It's 
Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges

Comment: `Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' FILE: Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets` Your `.xproj` file may be screwed up or be a legacy thing VS 2015 didn't fix... can you post your `.xproj` somewhere?

Comment: @AndrésRobinet it's very small `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ActiveDebugProfile>IIS Express</ActiveDebugProfile>
    <ShowAllFiles>false</ShowAllFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>`

Comment: I just managed to get it to add a migration by copying everything in the `win10-x64` folder to it's parent folder where it was looking for the .deps file. Only strange thing now is it isn't creating the database on my local postgres install

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2802
According to that thread it seems people are manually copying the .dep file. I would think they would have a fix already but maybe not so. They do mention spaces in the name being an issue but my project names do not have spaces. The full path does.. Just not the project name

Answer (score 23):

Select proper Startup Project in your solution : Right-click on your project in the solution explorer, select  "Set as startup project"

Answer (score 4):

Select the project that your entities included as Startup Project (Right-click on your project in the solution explorer and select "Set as startup project") and be sure that you installed [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design/) package. May be this is not best solution but solved my same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, brand new .Net Core 2.2 MVC app, the issue was resolved by selecting a startup object:

1. Right-click on your app
2. Choose 'Properties'
3. In the 'Application' tab, the "*Startup object*" dropdown list had the value "(Not set)". Selecting the (only) other available item "*MyAppName.Program*" did the trick for me.