# dotnet : Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have this error when trying to execute `dotnet ef migrations add "initial"` in the Package Manager Console

This is the output error [image: Image Error]

I try to fix the problem using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176240/ef-core-1-1-migration-the-current-csharphelper-cannot-scaffold-literals-of-typ) , but that not working

This is my project.json file

```js
{
  "userSecretsId": "Jobs",
  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper.Data": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "FastJobsProject.BLL": "1.0.0-*",
    "FastJobsProject.Entity": "1.0.0-*",
    "FluentValidation": "6.2.1-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    } 
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcConcurrent": true,
    "gcServer": true
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Can Anyone explain me the meaning of above error and solution to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for solutions and trying them in my case, I came to a conclusion that the incompatibilities between dependencies version is the problem.

This is my new project.json that work correctly [image: correctly] :

```js
{
  "userSecretsId": "Jobs",

  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper.Data": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "FastJobsProject.BLL": "1.0.0-*",
    "FastJobsProject.DAL": "1.0.0-*",
    "FastJobsProject.Entity": "1.0.0-*",
    "FluentValidation": "6.2.1-beta1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
     "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true,
    "gcConcurrent": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I hope it can help if someone get the same problem.